# Twice version of python in Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pyqt4, pycharm

I wold like to use Pycham with Python3.4.3 and Pyqt4.
So, I have installed Python 3.4.3 in Ubuntu 16.04 and run PyQt4 as well. After that, I continued installing Pycharm. However, pycharm interpreter didn't recognized these version of python. It only shows python 3.5 and 2.7 version. However, when I run in terminal python3.4>>import PyQt4, there isn't wrong message. I think that all compilation that I have to do was right. Anyone know what can I do to fix this problem?

How can I put Pycharm to recognize python3.4.3 that I installed with PyQt4?

[image: This show that my python3.4.3 is working well with PyQt4 in my notebook]

[image: But We can't see python3.4.3 in Pycharm]

Comment: Did you try adding the interpreter? i.e hit the + and search for the python3.4 bin?

Comment: Yes. But It didn't apper. There is one answer that I belive good, but it have disappear. Maybe, the problem was how I install python.

Comment: If python3.4 works from the shell then you installed it just fine, you just need to find the path which is most likely somewhere under /usr/local, start a shell with python3.4 and `import sys; sys.executable`. Apart from that what is wrong with using python3.5, why do you need 3.4.3?

Comment: Padraic Cunningham perfect your answer. It worded well. Thank you so much!!! If you can, put your comment like answer in order to check the topic like answered.

Comment: no worries, glad it helped.